# IOS: how to use UITableView as Newsfeed view for Facebook like application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook, uitableview

I am working on a Facebook like app in which i have to view friends updates on newsfeed just same as Facebook. For my app's newsfeed I am using `UITableView` but now I am confused how to design dynamic table view calls for newsfeed which shows texts and images separately or in the same cell.
Please suggest me solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subclass your UITableViewCell to create a custom UITableViewCell.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702